# Cancel jobs submitted previous to a date or with JOBID lower than a given integer

Tags: slurm

I have realized that the jobs submitted with a previous version of my software are useless because of a bug, so I want to cancel them. However, I also have newer jobs that I would like to keep running. All the jobs have the same job name and are running in the same partition.

I have written the following script to cancel the jobs with an ID lower than a given one.

```
#!\bin\bash

if [ $1 ]
then
    MAX_JOBID=$1
else
    echo "An integer value is needed"
    exit
fi

JOBIDLIST=$(squeue -u $USER -o "%F")

for JOBID in $JOBIDLIST
do
    if [ "$JOBID" -lt "$MAX_JOBID" ]
    then
        echo "Cancelling job "$JOBID
        scancel $JOBID
    fi
done
```

I would say that this is a recurrent situation for someone developing a software and I wonder if there is a direct way to do it using slurm commands. Alternatively, do you use some tricks like appending the software commit ID to the job name to overcome this kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the suggestions by @j23, you can organise your jobs with

- [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) ; if all your jobs are similar in terms of submission script, make them a job array, and submit one job array per version of your software. Then you can cancel an entire job array with just one `scancel` command
- a workflow management system ; they enable submitting and managing sets of jobs (possibly on different clusters) easily

  - Fireworks https://materialsproject.github.io/fireworks/
  - Bosco https://osg-bosco.github.io/docs/
  - Slurm pipelines https://github.com/acorg/slurm-pipeline
  - Luigi https://github.com/spotify/luigi

Comment: I use job arrays to group parameter configurations, but as you have said it is the first approach to consider.

Comment: I didn't know about the workflow management systems that you mention. Thanks for the suggestion. I have always used slurm directly from the command line. Do they need admin privileges in the cluster for the installation? At first glance, it seems that Firework and Lugi need admin privileges, slurm-pipelines does not need and I am not sure if Bosco really needs privileges in the slurm sever. Is this correct?

Comment: Some of them might need administrative privileges to be installed, but most of the time they need not be installed on the cluster. They are installed either on your personal computer or on a dedicated server. Fireworks is best for team work on a dedicated server, while Bosco is more suited for personal use on your laptop. The others I know less about them.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is **no direct way** to cancel the job in such scenarios.

Alternatively, like you pointed out, naming the job by adding software version/commit along with job name is useful. In that case you can use, `scancel --name=JOB_NAME_VERSION` to cancel all the jobs with that job name.

Also, if newly submitted jobs can be `hold` using `scontrol hold <jobid>` and then all the `PENDING` job can be cancelled using `scancel --state=PENDING`

In my case, I used a similar approach (like yours) by having `squeue` piped the output to `awk` and cancelled the first N number of jobs I wanted to remove. Its a one-liner script.

Something like this:

eg: `squeue arguments | awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=N{print $1}' | xargs /usr/bin/scancel`

Comment: Nice approach! I am sure it is useful in many cases.